# How to read csv file by using headers using java?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file which contains 5 header fields like field1,field2,field3,field4,field5.
The file contains data for this headers for different users.
Some columns may contains null values as only three columns are compulsary.

I want to read columns by specifying its header, something like if I specified field1 and field3 then read values of these columns only.

I tried opencsv to do that and readAll Function of opencsv.
I also tried CSVReader.

Here is my code :

```
public void startScanFile(){
String mydemofile=pathtofile;
BufferedReader br =null;
try {
  System.out.println("\nEnter the column number that contains ip : ");
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  ipcolumn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      System.out.println("\nEnter the column number that contains username : ");
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  usercolumn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  System.out.println("\n Enter the column number that contains password");
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  passcolumn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }catch(Exception e){
}
try {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(mydemofile));
    String[] row;
    while ((row = csvReader.readNext())!=null){
    System.out.println("Col1 is is : " + row[1]);
    System.out.println("Col3 is : " + row[3]);
    System.out.println("Col4 is : " + row[4]);
}
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

How can I read values of specified headers only?

Comment: what you got so far? or at least show us the sample of the file content

Comment: please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @RafaEl I used opencsv api and its function readAll to read csv and extract information from result.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you using `csvreader` you can use this

```
line.get("field3");
```

http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html#get(java.lang.String)

http://javacsv.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following csv library. Its good. Check the below url which contains the example how to get the csv data using header and you can also validate the data.

```
http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html
```